# When clicking on a div change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the background image of the div to change to 'rustb.png' when ever the user is holding down on the div with a click and then return to 'rust.jpg' when they let go of the div (stop holding down click). This is what I have and it isn't doing anything when I click on the div.

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Img Change Testing </title>
</head>

<style>
#noclick {
    background-image: url("rust.jpg");
    width: 33%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#pushclick {
    background-image: url("rustb.png");
    width: 33%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="noclick" onclick="mouseState(e)">

    <p>This is an image</p>

</div>

</body>

<script>
$( "img.noclick" )
.mousedown(function() {
$( this ).prop("id", 'pushclick');
})
.mouseup(function() {
$( this ).prop("id", 'noclick');
});
</script>
</html>
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: @j08691 "Moustate is not defined"?

Comment: Is that the only error? If so, why do you have `onclick="mouseState(e)"`?

Comment: @j08691 I see where that came from and removed the onclick="..." and the only error left is "$ is not define".

Comment: That means you didn't include jQuery

Comment: @j08691 how would I do that?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: `img.noclick` should be `#noclick`. Tha's what happens when you copy paste code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues,

1. You dont have any image tag
2. You are accessing div using class selector which is incorrect.
3. You should wrap your jQuery event binding in ready()

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Img Change Testing</title>
</head>

<style>
  #noclick {
    background-image: url("rust.jpg");
    width: 33%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    color: red;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
  #pushclick {
    background-image: url("rustb.png");
    width: 33%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    color: green;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div id="noclick">

    <p>This is an image</p>

  </div>

</body>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#noclick").mousedown(function() {
        $(this).attr("id", 'pushclick');
      })
      .mouseup(function() {
        $(this).attr("id", 'noclick');
      });

  });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div id="noclick" onclick="mouseState(e)">
    <p>This is an image</p>
  </div>

$("#noclick").on("mousedown", function() {
    $( this ).attr("id", 'pushclick');
   });
$("body").on("mouseup","#pushclick",function() {
  $( this ).attr("id", 'noclick');
   });
```

[fiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/qrwhw0gr/2/)